# question on importing multiple csv files in python system

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question on importing multiple csv files such that they are vertically stacked into a column array.

[Here is a a sample; all the files look the same]:

```
yyyymm count_neg count_pos count_all score 
200301 114 67 7470 0.006291834 
200303 106 51 3643 0.015097447 
200305 102 62 3925 0.010191083 
200306 129 71 4964 0.011684126 
200308 53 50 3819 0.000785546 
200309 59 58 3926 0.000254712 
200310 50 63 3734 -0.003481521 
200312 75 55 4256 0.004699248
```

This particular set of data is from a excel sheet called 2003.csv
I also have similar file names for years 2004, 2005, 2006

So again I  am wondering how to get these into python such that: I vertically stack these csv into a column array

Right now, all I know how to do is this:

```
yr2003 = pandas.read_csv('2003.csv', header=0,parse_dates=True)
```

While df = pd.concat([yr2003, yr2004, yr2005]) does indeed combine things, I am only looking to combine yyyymm and count_all score columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

df = pd.concat([yr2003, yr2004, yr2005])